# style select tag when dropdown is open

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know if there is a pure css way to apply styles to a select tag only when the dropdown is open. I thought that maybe the :active, or :focus would do what I was hoping for, but it's not quite right. It's possible to for a select tag to have a focused state without the dropdown being open, so the style still applies. I know I can very easily add some javascript to accomplish this, but I am looking for a pure css way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't really a way to do this. Using the `:enabled` tag will just style the select box, when unclicked.

You can try making your own select box with HTML/CSS and a little bit of JS.
**[here is a great tutorial](http://www.scribbletribe.com/how-to-style-the-select-dropdown/)** on how to do so.

Comment: I don't want to style the dropdown, just the actual select input element. But  I still don't think what I want can be accomplished without javascript, just thought I would ask before I do it.

Answer (score -1):

I would try doing :enabled but if that doesn't work here is a reference to all the style selectors.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

EDIT: I just did some testing and :focus only applied when it was open.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: Sadly the link I provided is a long list of CSS selectors, it would take a lot of time to copy all of them out into my answer. The list would then also be invalid if the :enabled selector turns out to be the corrent one, as I've provided it in the answer.

Comment: We'll it's kind of an answer..but it's more of a comment IMO. If you'd tested it in a demo and if it worked *then* it's more of an answer.

Comment: When I tried :focus, the style was applied when the element had focus, obviously, but it could have focus when the dropdown was either open or closed. ie. click on the element to open it, the style is applied because it has focus; click on the element again to close it, the style is applied because, even though the dropdown is closed, it still has focus. Haven't tried :enabled yet, but I will.

Comment: Just read into enabled and tried it. Styles applied to all enabled input elements, so basically when they are in their normal state.